# Rails Admin - message before update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I use rails_admin.

Does anybody know how I can show confirmation message (with actions) before update ?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom action or override existing one.  Something like this:

```
class Update2
  RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)
  register_instance_option :visible? do
    # 
  end
  register_instance_option :link_icon do
    # your icon here
  end
  register_instance_option :http_methods do
    [:get, :post]
  end
  register_instance_option :controller do
    Proc.new do
      if request.post?
        @object.update
        flash[:notice] = "Updated #{@object.name}."
        redirect_to show_path
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then create a page app/views/rails_admin/main/update2.html.haml

```
%h3 
  = "Are you sure you want to update '#{@object.name}'
= link_to 'Update', update2_path, method: 'post', class: "btn btn-danger"
= link_to 'Cancel', show_path, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

When you click Update2 you will go to the page via GET.  Then on POST it will actually update.

Comment: Thanks, it can be a solution.